# Rel: the category of relations

Tags: category-theory, terminology, relations

$\text{Rel}$ is the standard name for the category of sets and [relations](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/Rel).

Confusingly in ["Abstract and concrete categories"](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) (ACC), page 22, $\text{Rel}$ is defined as a category whose objects are pairs $\langle X,\rho \rangle$ (where $\rho$ is a relation on set $X$) and morphisms are relation-preserving functions. The standard category of sets and relations -apparently- is not mentioned anywhere.

Question: is there a standard name for the category described in ACC ?

Comment: Yes, both categories are often denoted by $\Bbb{Rel}$, but in most cases they don't turn up in the same context.

Comment: The category you're considering is extensively studied in the book [Categories, Allegories](http://books.google.it/books?id=fCSJRegkKdoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=categories+allegories&hl=it&sa=X&ei=GrdsU_CuJtLQ7Abh_ICICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=categories%20allegories&f=false) by Freyd and Ščedrov.

Answer (score 2):

Both categories are denoted by $\mathrm{Rel}$. In most cases, however, the author either explicitly tells which $\mathrm{Rel}$ he/she is using, or reproduces the definition of $\mathrm{Rel}$. (Note: this applies to any definition/term in math which can be used for two different things.) As egreg has mentioned in the comments, [*Categories, Allegories*, Freyd and Ščedrov](http://books.google.com/books?id=fCSJRegkKdoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) covers this.

Perhaps what you're looking for is a relation between $\mathrm{Rel}$ as defined in [$\mathit{ACC}$, p. $22$](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) and $\mathrm{Rel}$ in the standard sense. If so, then note that $\mathrm{Rel}$ as defined in [$\mathit{ACC}$, p. $22$](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) is $\mathrm{Rel}$ in the standard sense with an extra condition that the $2$-morphisms in $\mathrm{Rel}$ (in the standard sense) are relation-preserving maps, which are also morphisms in $\mathrm{Set}$, since the $2$-morphisms in $\mathrm{Rel}$ in the standard sense not only take relations $\rho\to\sigma$, but also takes the sets $X\to Y$.

Comment: thank you Sanath. Indeed I was ultimately interested in the relation between the 2 categories. Could you perhaps express this relation just using the language of basic category theory (i.e. avoiding higher categories theory)?

Comment: @magma Yes - of course. If we label each relation as the vertex of a graph, then the mappings $X\to Y$ are the (directed) edges of the aforementioned graph.