# How would you describe category the $\mathsf{Rel}$?

Tags: notation, category-theory, terminology, definition

I encountered two definitions for a category denoted by $\mathsf{Rel}$:

- Objects are pairs $\left(A,R\right)$ where $A$ is a set and $R$
  a relation on $A$. Arrows in $\mathsf{Rel}\left(\left(A,R\right),\left(B,S\right)\right)$
  are functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ with $aRa'\Rightarrow f\left(a\right)Sf\left(a'\right)$.
- Objects are sets and arrows in $\mathsf{Rel}\left(A,B\right)$
  are relations $R\subset A\times B$.

In [ACC](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) I met the first category but not the second, and in CWM 
the second category but not the first (it is not unthinkable that
I overlooked).

I don't see a direct connection between them. Is there any? Are there
alternative names/notations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not overlook. ACC and CWM define different categories with the same name. You can also see my linked question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/787706/19609

Comment: @magma Thank you. The answer of SDevalapurkar was pointing me in that direction too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787706/rel-the-category-of-relations/790481#790481) that I wrote a few months ago, which should pertain to this question as well:

> Both categories are denoted by $\mathrm{Rel}$. In most cases, however, the author either explicitly tells which $\mathrm{Rel}$ he/she is using, or reproduces the definition of $\mathrm{Rel}$. (Note: this applies to any definition/term in math which can be used for two different things.) As egreg has mentioned in the comments, [*Categories, Allegories*, Freyd and Ščedrov](http://books.google.com/books?id=fCSJRegkKdoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) covers this.
>
> Perhaps what you're looking for is a relation between $\mathrm{Rel}$ as defined in [$\mathit{ACC}$, p. $22$](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) and $\mathrm{Rel}$ in the standard sense. If so, then note that $\mathrm{Rel}$ as defined in [$\mathit{ACC}$, p. $22$](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) is $\mathrm{Rel}$ in the standard sense with an extra condition that the $2$-morphisms in $\mathrm{Rel}$ (in the standard sense) are relation-preserving maps, which are also morphisms in $\mathrm{Set}$, since the $2$-morphisms in $\mathrm{Rel}$ in the standard sense not only take relations $\rho\to\sigma$, but also takes the sets $X\to Y$.